# Where can I find this "standard elliptical argument"?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I recently came across the following problem:

Assume $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and \begin{equation} \Vert w \Vert_{L^\infty (B(x_0,1))} \leq C \end{equation} for some real constant $C>0$, where $B(x_0,1)$ denotes the unit ball around $x_0$.

My professor than stated that "standard elliptic theory" leads to \begin{equation} \vert \nabla w(x_0) \vert \leq K \left( \Vert \Delta w \Vert_{L^\infty (B(x_0,1))} + \Vert w \Vert_{L^\infty (B(x_0,1))} \right). \end{equation}

My question is

> What kind of "standard elliptic" argument is this? Where can I find such an argument?

Comment: Is $w$ in $C^2_0(B(x_0,1))$ as well?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Yes, I can assume that. Is there such an argument then? EDIT: oh sorry, I misread. No, it does not have compact support, but still may assumed to be smooth.

Comment: I think your professor first used the Taylor expansion
$$
w(x) = w(x_0) + \nabla w\cdot (x-x_0) + \frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^T D^2w(\xi) (x-x_0)
$$
If choosing $x = x_0 + \epsilon e_i$, i.e., the first order will have the $i$-th component of $\nabla u$:
$$\epsilon|(\nabla u)_i| = \left|w(x_0) - w(x) + \frac{1}{2}(x-x_0)^T D^2w(\xi) (x-x_0)\right|\\
 \leq \sup_{x\in B(x_0,1)}|w| + \epsilon^2\sup_{x\in B(x_0,1)}|D^2 w|$$ However I am not sure how he can bound $|D^2 w|$ by Laplacian, for standard "elliptic argument" applies for $C^{2,\alpha}$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant estimates can be found in Section 3.4 (*Gradient estimates for Poisson's equation*) in the book *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order* by Gilbarg and Trudinger. It is convenient to write $w=h+u$ where $h$ is harmonic with the same boundary values as $w$. By the maximum principle, $h$ is bounded by $\|w\|_{L^\infty}$, and the gradient estimate for harmonic functions (also found in GT, or see [Interior gradient bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188387/79365)) gives an estimate for $|\nabla h(x_0)|$ in terms of $\sup|h|$.

To the function $u$ you can apply inequality $(3.16)$ in GT, which says 
$$\sup_\Omega d_x|\nabla u| \le C(\sup_\Omega |u|+\sup_\Omega d^2_x |\Delta u|)$$
where $d_x=\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial \Omega)$.

Comment: Nice answer +1.