# Estimates on derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let U $\subset R^n$ be open, and $u:U \Rightarrow$ R be harmonic and nonnegative. Prove that

$|Du(x_0)| \le \frac{n}{r} u(x_0)$, $\forall x_0 \in U$, $\forall B(x_0,r) \subset U$

I really need someone's help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Think this is discussed quite well in Gilbarg and Trudinger chapter 2

Comment: Actually there is a very similar proof in Evans's book but they are different. Could you give me some ideas? Thanks

Comment: Where did you found this statament?

Answer (score 0):

In [Interior gradient bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188387/) you will find a detailed proof of the estimate
$$|Du(x_0)|\le \frac{n}{r}[\sup_{U} u - u(x_0)] \tag{1}$$
This is essentially equivalent to the estimate you want. Indeed, given a nonnegative harmonic function $u$, apply (1) to $-u$:
$$|Du(x_0)|\le \frac{n}{r}[\sup_{U} (-u) + u(x_0)] \le \frac{n}{r}u(x_0) $$
as desired.